# Randomly find a write-able folder and create a file there

Tags: ruby, random, filesystems

How can I find a completely random folder on a user's file system, test that I have write permission, and then create a file in that folder?

I am planning to write a little "treasure hunt" puzzle application where clues are randomly distributed throughout your system and you have to find them.

I have no idea how to begin picking a random folder though.

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea.  =)

Comment: Enumerating all directories is going to be expensive I would think.  You could incrementally do it by successive `Dir.glob('*/')` calls, picking a random entry as you go, and stopping at a random depth.  Also, let us know what this program will be called so we can **never accidentally run it**.

Comment: " where clues are randomly distributed throughout your system and you have to find them "  yeah.  not on my system either.

Comment: @NickVeys I'm planning to call it "treasure hunt.exe"

Answer (score 0):

I still say this is a bad idea... but to answer your question:

You can use the `Dir` class, start in / and grab a list of all directories, then pick one randomly and transverse into it, check if you can write, and then repeat the process.  Making note of those directories you have write access in.

It's not going to be quick.